# Reset filter p-tree primeng

Tags: html, filter, tree, primeng

I'm looking for a solution for my problem. I'm using a PrimeNG tree for an aside menu. When I click a button in screen to navigate, tree is rebuilded with new options. However, in the first menu, if I search an option with the filter of a p-tree, filter works fine, but, if I navigate, filter keeps input text, and options in the second menu are not showed till I clean the input filter.

¿Is there a possibility to clean the filter automatically?

I attach images for more details.

Expected behaviour:
[image: First page]
[image: Second page]
Current behaviour
[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

The HTML code is:

```
<p-tree [value]="files3" [filter]="true" filterMode="strict" selectionMode="single" scrollHeight="200px"></p-tree>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I answer my onw question

It's necesary to give id to html element and execute function Tree resetFilter()

HTML code:

`<p-tree #tree [value]="files3" [filter]="true" filterMode="strict" selectionMode="single" scrollHeight="200px"></p-tree>`

Then, in TS:

```
@ViewChild('tree') tree;

this.tree.resetFilter();
```